# Determine the exact user when running shell in php via the web server?

Tags: php, shell, webserver

When accessing the php page via the web:

```
<?php
print '<pre>'."\n";

print 'Current script owner: '."\n";
print get_current_user()."\n";
print "\n";

print '$USER: '."\n";
passthru('print $USER');
print "\n";
```

I get the output:

```
Current script owner: 
danny

$USER:
```

Why is the shell user not equal to the current script owner? How to determine the user when running a shell in the php script via the web server?

Comment: Why _should_ the shell user be equal to the owner of the script? If you want to get the process username, there are lots of suggestions in the comments on the documentation page: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php

Comment: I found that `posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())` is also danny and `shell_exec('whoami')` is empty. How to configure the shell user when executing system commands by web php?

Comment: `$USER` and `whoami` are filled in by `login`. Since PHP is run as a daemon, it doesn't get these variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `USER` environment variable is filled in by the `login` program. Since PHP is run as a background daemon, the variable isn't normally set. You can set it with `putenv`:

```
$user = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid());
putenv('USER='.$user['name']);
```

Comment: I've made it work and thank you for this hint. But the posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid()) is an array with info; therefore the correct script should be: `<?php $user = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid()); putenv('HOME='.$user['dir']); putenv('USER='.$user['name']);`